# How to make an aggregation function based on calculation between 2 columns?

Tags: r

My dataframe is

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(4,4,4,2,2,2), y = c(1,2,3,1,2,3), y_share = c(0.2,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2))
```

I want to have an aggregation `df` with 2 columns of `y` and `z` with

```
z = sum(x*y_share)/sum(y_share).
```

In this case, the resulted dataframe should be like this:

```
result = data.frame(y = c(1,2,3), z = c(2.57, 3.14, 3))
```

I tried this

```
func = function(x) {y=sum(vector(x[1])*vector(x[3]))/sum(vector(x[3]))
                    return(y)}
agg = aggregate(df, by=list(df$y), FUN=func)
```

but it doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: your `df` is showing error

Comment: oops sorry, I have fixed it.

Comment: in your  `func`, there is some issue .  what is `vector`

Comment: when I run my func without vector(), it doesn't work so I tried with vector() to have element-wise calculation.

Comment: You can use `by` as in my solution

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually 'by' doesn't work (it gives the same 'z' for all 'y') so I use setTD instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(z = sum(x * y_share)/sum(y_share)), by = y]
#  y        z
#1: 1 2.571429
#2: 2 3.142857
#3: 3 3.000000
```

---

Or if we want to use `base R`, here is an option with `by`

```
stack(by(df, list(df$y), FUN = function(z)
       with(z, sum(x * y_share)/sum(y_share))))[2:1]
```

#### data

```
 df <-  data.frame(x=c(4,4,4,2,2,2), y=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
           y_share=c(0.2,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2))
```

Answer (score 1):

*Tidyverse* approach (using `dplyr`):

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  summarise(z = sum(x*y_share)/sum(y_share)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**Result**

```
result

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#       y     z
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1  2.57
# 2     2  3.14
# 3     3  3.
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(4,4,4,2,2,2), 
                 y = c(1,2,3,1,2,3), 
                 y_share = c(0.2,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2))

result <- data.frame(y = c(1,2,3), 
                     z = c(2.57, 3.14, 3))
```